# Python - Queue trade-off processing

Tags: python, queue

I have a queue with 100 numbers in it, from 1 to 100. First I have one process to fill the queue that prints `Queue filled`. Next I have two functions that print the current value of the queue. I'm trying to trade of between printing the values of the queue between the processes. Here's my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def fillQueue(lookup,q):
    list(map(q.put,lookup))
    print('Queue filled')

def printQueue1(q):
    while not q.empty():
        print('Process 1:', (q.get()))
    print('Process 1: Queue is empty!')

def printQueue2(q):
    while not q.empty():
        print('Process 2:', (q.get()))
    print('Process 2: Queue is empty!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()

    lookup = []
    count = 1
    while count < 101:
        lookup.append(count)
        count = count + 1

    p2 = pool.apply_async(printQueue1,(q,))
    p3 = pool.apply_async(printQueue2,(q,))
    p1 = pool.apply_async(fillQueue,(lookup,q))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This gives me:

```
Process 1: 1
Process 1: 2
Process 1: 3
Process 1: 4
Process 1: 5
Process 2: 6
Process 1: 7
Process 2: 8
Process 1: 9
Process 2: 10
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
Queue filled
Process 1: 1
Process 2: 2
Process 1: 3
Process 2: 4
Process 1: 5
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? Each time I run the program I get different results, so something weird is happening. Thanks!

Comment: The queue items are not evenly distributed between the processes. Process 1 seems to be a bit faster for whatever reason. This is perfectly ok. If you want an even distribution you may need additional synchronization (locks) but this would make the use of two print processes instead of one actually pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Queue` object for each process to act as a "baton" to signal which process gets to dequeue the next item from the main queue, and then in the main loop of each worker function, it should first try to dequeue from its own "baton" queue before trying to dequeue from the main queue, after which it should "pass the baton" to the next process by enqueuing an item into the "baton" queue of the next process. The queuing process should kick off the dequeuing processes by enqueuing an item into the "baton" queue of the process that should run first. This works because `Queue.get` blocks until there is an item in the queue:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def fillQueue(lookup, q, baton_first):
    list(map(q.put,lookup))
    print('Queue filled')
    baton_first.put(None)

def printQueue(id, q, baton_self, baton_other):
    while True:
        baton_self.get()
        try:
            if q.empty():
                break
            print('Process %s:' % id, (q.get()))
        # use finally to always pass on the baton whether the loop breaks or not
        finally:
            baton_other.put(None)
        time.sleep(1) # the actual work should be performed here
    print('Process %s: Queue is empty!' % id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()
    baton1 = manager.Queue()
    baton2 = manager.Queue()

    p2 = pool.apply_async(printQueue,(1, q, baton1, baton2))
    p3 = pool.apply_async(printQueue,(2, q, baton2, baton1))
    p1 = pool.apply_async(fillQueue, (list(range(1, 11)), q, baton1))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This outputs:

```
Queue filled
Process 1: 1
Process 2: 2
Process 1: 3
Process 2: 4
Process 1: 5
Process 2: 6
Process 1: 7
Process 2: 8
Process 1: 9
Process 2: 10
Process 1: Queue is empty!
Process 2: Queue is empty!
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was trying to do! Question, when I increase the `count` to 100, the "Queue filled" message appears after the processing starts. So how is it processing the Queue if it hasn't been filled yet? Or is the "Queue filled" message being displayed late?

Comment: Glad to be of help. This is because all 3 processes run concurrently, so the `print('Queue filled')` statement does not necessarily get run before the queue gets dequeued. If you really want to have that message always printed before any dequeuing starts, you can make that process, instead of the main process, execute the `baton1.put(None)` statement to kick off the dequeuing. I've updated my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

So, `apply_async` *applies processes asyncronously* - this means that the 3 processes you're triggering to run all run at the same time and are sort of fighting with one another.

Since you aren't triggering these processes deterministically, the order in which they run will likely change each time you trigger the process.

I'm assuming you want:

1. The Queue to fill BEFORE the processes attempt to access it
2. The "work" to be spread equally between the processes

Even so, unless you constrain the functions in some way, the order they'll `get()` items is still fairly random. If you truly need function1 to only get odds, and function2 to only get evens, and for them to be in strict order, you probably don't want multiprocessing...

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def fillQueue(lookup, q):
    list(map(q.put, lookup))
    print('Queue filled')


def printQueue(q, id):
    while not q.empty():
        print('Process {}: {}'.format(id, q.get()))
    print('Process {}: Queue is empty!'.format(id))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()

    # no need to construct a list with a counter, we can just use the generator
    lookup = range(101)

    # do not fill the queue while processes are running, do it beforehand!
    fillQueue(lookup, q)

    # don't need different functions, since they are doing the same work
    # just fire off multiple copies of the same function
    p1 = pool.apply_async(printQueue, (q, 1,))
    p2 = pool.apply_async(printQueue, (q, 2,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Example output:

```
Queue filled
Process 2: 0
Process 2: 1
Process 2: 2
Process 2: 3
Process 2: 4
Process 2: 5
Process 1: 6
Process 2: 7
Process 1: 8
Process 2: 9
Process 2: 10
Process 1: 11
```

Comment: Your explanation of how the queue works was helpful. Thank you for that!